# Write Procedure Name correctly formated in algorithm environment

Tags: algorithms

I want to call a function in an algorithm environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Recursion}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Recursion}{$a$}
    \State $a\gets Recursion(a)$ \Comment{Call Recursion again}
    \State \textbf{return} $a$ 
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

What do I have to do to get the "correct" style for the word "Recursion" in the line `\State $r\gets Recursion(a)$`?

I tried something like `\State $r\gets \Procedure{Recursion}{a}$`, but only received errors.
The official documentation has no exmple regarding this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"? Small caps? Please explain, what you are having. At the moment you are writing `$R\cdot e\cdot c\cdot ... \cdot n(a)$` which happens when writing text like this in math mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think that you can print the content of your procedure somewhere else as you have tried by `\State $a\gets \Procedure{Recursion}{a}$`.

You could do this by styling manually. You may use `\textsc` in math mode to do so. You can also add a `\Comment` (see in the example I provided). Instead of `\textsc` you may also use `\Call`. Sometimes either `\textsc` or `\Call` [will not behave as expected](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16056/251607).

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Recursion}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Recursion}{$a$}
    \State $a\gets\Call{Recursion}(a)$ \Comment{Call Recursion again}
    \State \textbf{return} $a$ 
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The answer by @Cubic shows how to do it "correctly"

Answer (score 7):

The intended way to do this in the `algorithmicx` package is with the `\Call` macro, ex:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
   \Function{Fix}{f}
      f(\Call{Fix}{f})
   \EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Recursion}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Recursion}{$a$}
    \State $a\gets$ \Call{Recursion}{$a$} \Comment{Call Recursion again}
    \State \textbf{return} $a$ 
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Which rendered:
[image: recursion]