# Numbered list instead of bullet points within a table

Tags: tables, lists

I am using the following code borrowed from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150650/203675) and modified accordingly to write down the steps of an algorithm:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{l}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Algorithm} } 
    \\
    \midrule
    \tabitem This is step 1 \\
    \tabitem This is step 2 \\
    \tabitem This is step 3 \\
    \tabitem This is step 4 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I want to have numbered list instead of bullet points.
How can this be done? I am not able to use the `enumerate` environment as the code is not compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick 'n' dirty...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\tabitem}[1]{~~\llap{#1.}~~}% <-- Modified

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{l}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Algorithm} } 
    \\
    \midrule
    \tabitem{1} This is step 1 \\
    \tabitem{2} This is step 2 \\
    \tabitem{3} This is step 3 \\
    \tabitem{4} This is step 4 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ Dr. Manuel Kuehner, can you please tell how the font size of the numbers can be reduced? I want to have the font size as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188372) .

Comment: Using the normal font size commands, e. g. \tiny{#1. }